# User management for Node.js/React

Tags: node.js, react-native, user-management, session-management

Our tool is a Node.js server / React client running on a network with **no** external web access.

We would like to add robust user management including:

- User definition (name, password, access level)
- Password change
- Login/Logout

Is there any open source libraries out there that can supply these capabilities?

Comment: Are you looking for a single sign-on?   https://auth0.com try this. If this is what you want?

Comment: @damitj07 We don't have external web access, so Auth0 is not an option. is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passport js](http://www.passportjs.org/) library provides a lot of strategies for authentication and authorization without requiring you to reinvent the wheel. You can use any of the databases to store the user's on the backend like MongoDB, Mysql, etc.

It can also talk to inhouse LDAP or auth server API if you decide to do so. All in all, this sounds like a perfect library for you.

Here is a tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: you can use any of the `express-session` or `cookie-parser` to store sessions .

Comment: Thanks! how can I limit number of concurrent client sessions per account?

Comment: you will have to maintain the active session in a DB or some persistence place. And before creating a new session check if a session already exists for that user, if it does send the session or perform logic as per your requirement. 

Sidenote- please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks.